# Javascript Put focus and cursor to an input box when the CLEAR button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a form where the user/visitor enters their information, like first name, last name and e-mail address.

I have two buttons in using **input type="reset"** and **input type="submit"**.

I would like to accomplish that if the user clicks the CLEAR (reset) button, the cursor should get back to a specific input box.

Below is how I am trying to achieve this, but I do not get it to work. 
For the record, I am using **Safari** as web browser.

```
function cleared()
    {
    var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox");
    var sub = document.getElementById("submit");
    cb.checked = false;
    sub.disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('firstname').focus();
    document.getElementById('firstname').select();
    }
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<input id="clear" type="reset" name="reset" value="Rensa" onclick="cleared();">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

//Andreas

Comment: `cb1` isn't defined (this will throw an error), `element` is never used.

Comment: It would help to see your HTML. Also, did you mean to have both `cb` and `cb1`? As tymeJV pointed out, `cb1` isn't in your local scope and will error unless it is global.

Comment: And the id of your checkbox is actually checkbox?

Comment: Yes, the **id** of the checkbox is actually checkbox.